# string.Format alternatives

Tags: c#, string

I think verbatim (multiline) strings in C# is a really great idea. I used to copy SQL from/to code minimizing typo errors.
Actually I need to render some javascript and I hit the wall.

The need of double quotes can be partially avoided using apostrophes in javascript, but in case you need format strings you also have to escape curly brackets:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), this.GetType().FullName, @"
<script type=""text/javascript"">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_button').click(function() {
   alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  });
 });
</script>
");
```

looks like with string.Format

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), this.GetType().FullName, string.Format(@"
<script type=""text/javascript"">
 $(document).ready(function() {{
  $('#{0}').click(function() {{
   alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  }});
 }});
</script>
"), buttonName);
```

I do not want to compromise speed of formating execution just to have easier life while coding using some sort of formating string preprocessing.
I hope there is some smart and easy way. Just do not want to reinvent wheel...

Thanks

Comment: hi. I know why you ask this question and be sure you will find many way (or answers). But I strongly recommended to change your way. Please do not use old style (before jquery seletors) javascript technic for asp.net pages.

Comment: Can you explain more? What is that old javascript technic?

Comment: please suppose, why you need to know ClintID? You could change your javascript blocks logic what they do not need to know id's. May be you can use Jquery selectors and you can remove Id related  event or methods. Forexample your JS code, try to define event delegate (click) with #my_button selector. Suppose it is inside of one defined div or etc and your selector will find button Id. Possible? I think that yes.

Comment: Well this is simplified example to demonstrate string.Format. But how you pass additional parameters if your control has one? I mean that case, your ASP control has some custom options, that changes result javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hope there is some smart and easy way.

Nope, just this incredibly slow and klunky way:

```
EscapeCurlies(String Input)
{
    String Temp = Input.Replace("{", "{{");
    Temp = Temp.Replace("}", "}}");

    Temp = Regex.Replace(Temp, @"{{(\d+)}}", "{$1}");

    return Temp;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String buttonName = "bob";

    String FormatString = 
@"<script type=""text/javascript"">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#{0}').click(function() {
alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
});
</script>";

    String Test = string.Format(EscapeCurlies(FormatString), buttonName);
}
```

`

Comment: I do preformating with regexp in static string, than use preformated directly with string.format()

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did some profiling on this a while ago, and the truth is: you won't notice this at all. Even in tight loops over millions of iterations the difference was small.

For info though you might want to look at razor, where the engine takes over and split it in advance (razor views can be pre-compiled) - in which case it would be something like (not accounting for js encoding):

```
$('#@buttonName')...
```

Or (alternative):

```
$('#@(buttonName)')...
```

One final option is to just code against a class, and only add the class (at the server) to the button you want - then it is a constant:

```
$('.some-class')...
```